# How to make a reverse function decrypt for my encrypt function

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

This is the encrypt function and it works well

```
def encrypt(password):
    for i in (password):
        print(dict_Chiper[i])
        not_Encrpyted = ''.join(dict_Chiper[i] for i in password)
        Encrpyted = ''.join(reversed(not_Encrpyted))
    print(Encrpyted)
    return Encrpyted
```

This is the inverse dictionary I make in respect to dict_Chiper for encrypting

```
dict_Dechiper = {v: k for k, v in dict_Chiper.items()}
```

This is the faulty function. Is it also faulty in the dictionary? Should I make the dictionary manually?

```
def decrypt(password):
    not_Decrypted = reversed(password.split('\n', 12))
    print(not_Decrypted)
    Decrypted = ''.join(dict_Dechiper[j] for j in (not_Decrypted))
    print(Decrypted)
    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your `password = "abcabc"` and `dict_Chiper = {"a":"b", "b":"c", "c": "d", "d":"a"}`, the ciphered result would be `"dcbdcb"` and, without any changes, your decrypting code ends up throwing an exception: `KeyError: 'dcbdcb'`.

This is because `reversed(password.split('\n', 12))` is returning a list_reverseiterator object that won't actually iterate over the string you are trying to decrypt. Instead, it is iterating over a list that looks like `['dcbdcb']`. That's why it threw the key error.

To fix it, I removed the split statement, created a string from the reverse iterator and, to keep things consistent, returned the decrypted password:

```
def decrypt(password):
    not_Decrypted = ''.join(reversed(password))
    Decrypted = ''.join(dict_Dechiper[j] for j in (not_Decrypted))
    return Decrypted
```

And, because of the `'\n'` split, one can assume that you want to decrypt a string containing multiple passwords separated by `\n`. That would require a few changes:

```
def decrypt(password):
    not_Decrypted_list = [''.join(reversed(each_password)) for each_password in password.split('\n', 12)]
    not_Decrypted = '\n'.join(not_Decrypted_list)
    Decrypted = ''.join(dict_Dechiper[j] for j in (not_Decrypted))
    return Decrypted
```

- `not_Decrypted_list`: list with reversed encrypted passwords that were separated by `'\n'`.
- `not_Decrypted`: a string containing `not_Decrypted_list` elements separated by `'\n'`

Notice that there must be a `'\n': '\n'` mapping in your `dict_Dechiper`. Otherwise, it will throw a `KeyError: '\n'`

Comment: I mean if I want to decrypt "w3272wqVG13q7Auq63rCSPa5HJ3feQfe539N3y17ew48dY1Zna9188adn1NJ" then I will have to split it at 12 chars (thats for each letter in my dict which consist of 12 random chars) and then reverse it. I thought I had to use \n so it can read and decrypt it based on the dict I have made. I tried the code you made and it gives me error on not_Decrypted line. It just says invalid syntax. Any correction on this? And thank you for the brief explanation above :)